# Oracle SQL Left Join using multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

To be honest I am not sure how to layout this question, but I tried my best.

I am trying to join multiple tables. TableA has got no with TableE and TableF.

Observe the area in query where I tried to highlight with **
when it comes to TableE I joined with TableF which is further below. How to re-write this?

```
SELECT
            a.NAME,b.ID,c.CODE
FROM        SCHEMA.TABLEA A
            INNER JOIN SCHEMA.TABLEB b
                ON A.A_ID = B.B_ID
           INNER JOIN SCHEMA.TABLEC  C
                ON A.A_ID = C.C_ID
           LEFT JOIN SCHEMA.TABLED D
                ON A.A_ID =  D.D_ID
           **LEFT JOIN SCHEMA.TABLEE E
                ON D.D_ID = F.F_ID
           LEFT JOIN SCHEMA.TABLEF F
                ON E.E_ID = F.F_ID**
```

Comment: If you want to use table e you should link with any table in the join, you can't use columns from other table as you did with f

Comment: Yah. I get that with this sample. How to fix this? That's what I am trying to solve which I don't know.

Comment: Is there any primary/foreign key in table e that matches any field in any other table?

Comment: TableE and TableF are related and F and D are related.

Comment: So pass by table f and the by table e, let me post an example

Answer (score 1):

Since you stated that table f is realted to table d and table e is related to table f i think you just need to change the order of join as follow

```
SELECT
        a.NAME,b.ID,c.CODE
FROM        SCHEMA.TABLEA A
       INNER JOIN SCHEMA.TABLEB b
            ON A.A_ID = B.B_ID
       INNER JOIN SCHEMA.TABLEC  C
            ON A.A_ID = C.C_ID
       LEFT JOIN SCHEMA.TABLED D
            ON A.A_ID =  D.D_ID
       LEFT JOIN SCHEMA.TABLEF F
            ON D.D_ID = F.F_ID
       LEFT JOIN SCHEMA.TABLEE E
            ON E.E_ID = F.F_ID
```